# Android Studio not starting , failed to create a child event loop , cannot lock system folders

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio not starting, failed to create a child event loop, cannot lock system folders

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:81)
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:48)
>           at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:57)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:67)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:54)
>           at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.java:79)
>           at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:133)
>           at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:113)
>           at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:157)
>           at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:113)
>           at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:263)
>           at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
>           at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:127)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.(NioEventLoop.java:119)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:97)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:31)
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
>           ... 18 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
>           at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
>           at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.(PipeImpl.java:170)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
>           at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
>           at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
>           at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:125)
>           ... 22 more
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)

Comment: After many hours search finally found solution

Try this ,

1) open cmd with Run as administrator

2) type: netsh winsock reset

3) restart computer

After restart open Android Studio no error dialog showing me , open successfully.

Comment: I'm getting this same error. I have tried this above mentioned solution as well as every other solution I could possibly find on internet but its still isn't working out. Can you help ?

Comment: Can you send these details , which OS , 64/32 Bit , Windows Home/Professional . This will help to find issue

Comment: System Details:
Windows 10 Home (Single Language), 64-bit OS, x64-bit based processor.
And I have installed below mentioned Android Studio set-up which is basically Android Studio 2.1
Setup: android-studio-bundle-143.2790544-windows

Comment: I have tried many solutions like:

Running netsh winsock reset in cmd(admin)

1)  Setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to IPv6
2)  Disabling UAC
3)  Adding Android Studio in Windows Firewall allowed apps
4)  Uninstalling Avast
5)  Turning off WIndows Firewall
6)  Adding JDK_HOME as well in environmental variables 

but still none of the above would help me launch Android Studio 2.1

Just FYI, when I used to work on Android Studio 1.5, I use to get below error:
Internal HTTP server disabled Cannot start internal HTTP server

TIA

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the studio ;  Also try to run Genymotion VirtualBox with Nexus device , If emulator not running then it's network bridge issue which are not possible to resolve. Try to restore Windows 8/7.

Mostly these issues only coming on Win Home editions , with Win professional its working fine 100%.

Comment: I had already tried it several times. Anyhow, I was finally able to make it work by resetting my Windows 10.

Comment: How did you reset your Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to the `.vmoptions` file (in the home directory) solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

BEST AND Easy Solution:

1. Uninstall Android Studio
2. Install it again after restarting computer.

I had the same problem and it solved .